# Retrieve service from one bundle in another bundle extension

Tags: php, symfony

I have a bundle I am working on.  In the extension for configurations, I am dependant on a service defined in a different bundle, but I get messages that the service is not defined.  What can I do to call the services from the other bundle?

EDIT:  Here is how I am trying to get the session service.

This is the bundle extension (simplified)

```
class BundleExtension
{
    function load()
    {
        $this->container->get('bundle.service');
     }
 }
```

And here is the services.yml that I am using (again, simplified)

```
services:
    bundle.service:
        class: ServiceClass
        arguments: [ @session ]
```

The error I am getting is:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "session" does not exist.
```

Comment: Do you reference the other bundle in your AppKernel?

Comment: It's the framework bundle

Comment: Which service and how are you trying to call it?  You should not have to do anything special as long as the bundle is in AppKernel.

Comment: Using $container->get('session')?  Most of the time you will want to just use $request->getSession();  Consider updating your question with the error message as well as an example of how you are trying to access it.

Comment: Services are not available in the extension.  They are not even defined yet.  Might be time to go through the documentation.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to achieve? It may be that you need some kind of compiler pass - shttp://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html